# Adding member or alias to existing path in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

For the jobs -> apply action I want to "alias" the "create" action.

In rake routes it would look something like this:

https://gist.github.com/YOUConsulting/19b404759757898a6f4f#file-rake_routes-rb

I've tried to do it like this but I think this is not exactly what I'm looking for:

```
  resources :jobs, :only => [:show, :index, :create] do
    resources :apply, :only => [:index, :create] do
      member do 
        post :completed
      end
    end
    resources :share, :only => [:index, :create]
  end
```

In human words:

When the user submits the page located at `"/jobs/<job_id_here>/apply"` (the index view)  the result page (the create view) should be `"/jobs/<job_id_here>/apply/completed"` instead of `"/jobs/<job_id_here>/apply/`" .

**Reason:**

When we track users via Google Analytics we can't see if they submitted the form successfully since there is no difference between `"/apply"` and `"/apply"`  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, what about using a named route as path

Add a line at the end of your routes.rb

```
post '/jobs/:job_id/apply/completed', to: apply#create as: apply_job
```

And then in your new.html.haml

```
form_for :job, apply_job_path
```

This should call the create action of your apply controller.

Instead of apply you can use of course any name you want.

Comment: Thanks you are freaking awesome! :)